# How do I run arbitrary code when a Java HTTP Servlet session ends?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Our application requires that we serialize some of the user's session data to the filesystem if their session expires.  We would serialize it as is coming in but that would be too expensive due to the nature of our application.

If we can figure out a way to hook some sort of 'onSessionEnd' method we could run the cleanup code then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for your application.

There is a method on the interface called `onSessionDestroy` that shall be called when the session ends and you can perform serialization right then.

To setup the listener, you add into `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.app.session.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Do you know if onSessionDestroy gets called if the server is shut down cleanly (ie: by stopping a service rather than killing a process)?

Comment: It will depend on the configuration of the container. Some containers (e.g. Tomcat) persist sessions across restarts by default. In that case you will not see a session destroyed event but you will see session passivation (and session activation when the server starts up again).

Comment: The method is called `sessionDestroyed()`.